# Issue in Batch (Debug)

Tags: batch-file, debugging

I have an odd issue I've arrived at in an attempt to solve a problem from YouTube.

Goal/Intended Function:
  **[Check a string and identify if there is a duplicate digit.]**
  I have a situation where a string is entered by a user and my program splits it into numerical variables each with a single character. When a new character is assigned it is checked with all prior starting with the number below itself.

My issue:
  My comparison command is set up in an odd way I'm unsure how to fix.

```
if %%%temp%%%==%%%temp2%%% goto win
```

The effect I wanted to cause to happen was... Temp/temp2 is evaluated to their numerical value, then it is left with something like this...

```
if %%1%%==%%2%% goto win
```

Which simplifies to...

```
if %1%==%2% goto win
```

This is then supposed to compare those two points in the string. However, this command evaluates to the number in between percent signs. What should I do?

The full code:

```
@echo off
set /p string=
set /a num=0
call set %num%=%%string:~%num%,1%%
set /a num=1
:re2
call set %num%=%%string:~%num%,1%%
set /a temp=%num%-1
set temp2=%num%
:re3
if %%%temp%%%==%%%temp2%%% goto win
if %temp%==0 goto re4
set /a temp=%temp%-1
goto re3
:re4
set /a num=%num%+1
goto re2

:win
```

Comment: Your main issue as you accepted in your last question on the same code is one of missing a necessary delayed expansion statement. _The entire code looks a little awkward just to find out if a integer has repeated._

Comment: When using `Set /A` variables are read without their enclosing variable characters, **`%`** or **`!`**, however, there's an easier way of increasing or decreasing the increment, _e.g. `Set /A var+=1` or `Set /A var-=1`_. You should additionally avoid setting a local variable to the name of an existing system environment variable, _e.g. `%temp%`_. I'd advise that you consider creating some code to ensure that the target input characters assigned to `%string%` are actually integers as expected by the code.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you, I kinda got the impression it was discouraged due to the three hour timeout on excepting your own answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution]

I have found a way to call what I intended through a variable, I put the command in a variable then type the "call" for the variable on its' own line.

set ccc=if %%%aaa%%%==%%%bbb%%% goto win
echo %ccc%